# Inheriting defaultProps from superclass in React

Tags: inheritance, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I think some `props`, (for example, a *theme*), are so universal among components that it makes sense to extract their handling (to a superclass). Then it follows that their default value also belongs there.

However, what would be the idionatic way to achieve this in React?

```
class Base extends React.Component {
  bgColor() {
    switch (this.props.theme) {
      case 'Summer': return 'yellow'; break;
      case 'Autumn': return 'grey'; break;
      case 'Winter': return 'white'; break;
    }
  }
}
Base.defaultProps = {
  theme: 'autumn'
};
```

---

```
class Sky extends Base {
  render() {
    return <div style={{backgroundColor: this.bgColor()}}>{this.props.clouds}</div>;
  }
}
Sky.defaultProps = {
  clouds: []
};
```

...`defaultProps` is a *class* property (as opposed to *instance*), and there is no inheritance.

Comment: If you're looking for a purely React-based solution, have you considered setting any received props to the component's state, and using `getInitialState` to specify defaults if no props were received?

Comment: Hm, yes but I thought it really doesn't belong in `state` as it's not something that changes

Comment: In that case, you could just specify the default value in `bgColor()`.  If `this.props.theme == null` then return `'grey'`, otherwise, use the switch statement you already have.  I understand that this isn't quite as elegant as  using a superclass with a default prop, but I believe this would still work.

Comment: That would work, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By assigning `Sky.defaultProps` you hide the base ones. If you want to combine them, you'd need to explicitly do that, e.g.

```
Sky.defaultProps = Object.assign({}, Base.defaultProps, {
  clouds: []
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the correct way to do it, however, according to kangax's ES6 compatibility tables, `Object.assign` is not yet supported in `JSX`.

Comment: Since you were using classes, I gave a standard ES6 answer, assuming you were using Babel. You can always use `_.extend` or polyfill it yourself though.

Comment: I was looking into `es6-shim`, but then stumbled upon `React.__spread`. Is it a bad idea to use it?

Comment: @FelixKling It does... in as much as our source is run through `jsx`, which does handle a lot of `ES6` syntax and in fact has an implementation similar to `Object.assign`. However it doesn't touch literal `Object.assign` statements, which means I can't use it directly, because obviously browser support is very poor. Because of incompatibility with other software we use unfortunately `babel` is out of  the question